# How to display a "more item" in an ItemsControl when the number of elements is bigger than n?

Tags: c#, wpf, itemscontrol

I have an `ItemsControl` that displays tiles in a Windows 8 manner with 2 columns and 4 rows. Each tile is clickable and triggers a command that will load the selected item in another view.

My problem starts here: my bound `IList<>` can contain more than 8 elements at the time, but must display no more than 8 tiles.

What I am trying to achieve is to create a different type of tile (linked to another command) that will appear (ex: using a `Converter`) only when my `IList<>` is bigger than 8. Please check the drawing below to understand my aim.

[image: Awaited result]

So far I could limit the number of elements retrieved in the `IList<>` container to 7 whenever it is bigger than 8, but adding the "special" 8th element is still a mystery for me.

Comment: you may need to implement some logic in the collection, CompositeCollection is something what you need for mystery element

Comment: What shall happen when "12 more" is clicked: shall the control display 19 elements (= 7 + 12), or shall it display the next 7 elements with a "5 more" tile, or shall it display the next 6 elements with a "6 more" tile and a "previous page" tile?

Comment: @fmunkert when 12 more is displayed the total number of elements is 7 (displayed) + 12 (hidden). When ever I will click this 12th tile item I will handle the action with a command and display another type of page that will display all 19 elements in a DataGridView

Comment: IMO the easiest would be to use an ‘IEnumerable` as the binded property type and yield the special item when needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have used `CompositeCollection` to solve the problem this enables multiple collections and items to be displayed as a single list. more on [CompositeCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.compositecollection)

here is a sample

xaml

```xml
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="2" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:Int32}">
            <Border Margin="4"
                    Background="LightSkyBlue">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="15"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:String}">
            <Border Margin="4"
                    Background="MediumPurple">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontWeight="SemiBold"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>      
</ItemsControl>
```

note that I have defined data templates for two different types i.e. int and string which will help me render the same accordingly

```cs
    public ViewModel()
    {
        IEnumerable<int> originalData = Enumerable.Range(1, 12);
        Items = new CompositeCollection();
        Items.Add(new CollectionContainer() { Collection = originalData.Take(originalData.Count() > 8 ? 7 : 8) });
        if (originalData.Count() > 8)
            Items.Add(originalData.Count() - 7 + " more");
    }

    public CompositeCollection Items { get; set; }
```

whole idea is to limit the number of elements in the primary collection and add an extra element to the collection of different type eg original list is int and extra is a string

so item control will render all the elements in the collection and we can control the appearance based on the data type

you may also make use of `Attached Properties` or `Converters` to simplify this or perform more sophisticated functions.

result

[image: result]

Comment: Actually, a `CompositeCollection` is not necessary to implement this solution; an ordinary `ObservableCollection<object>` would also work.

Comment: Thank you pushpraj for this complete example, I didn't even know such collection were sortable with the DataType property. This is saving me alot of time and converters !

Comment: That's great! I am glad you liked it, you may experiment and dive into the versatility. Also a CompositeCollection does support collection changed notifications too just like an ObservableCollection. well good luck, happy coding :)