# In WPF How can I limit the number of items displayed in an ItemsControl?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a list that I want to allow a user to page through. I want to limit the number of items that are displayed then a user can click various buttons to go to the next item or next group of items. I found one implementation here using CompositeCollection I assume you would add and remove from that collection depending on whether you are clicking backwards or forwards. The same could be done with an observable collection.

[How to display a "more item" in an ItemsControl when the number of elements is bigger than n?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24625244/how-to-display-a-more-item-in-an-itemscontrol-when-the-number-of-elements-is-b)

I was wondering if I could limit the number of items using a ListView ViewBase and how I would implement that. Any other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Sounds like the kind of thing you would do in a CollectionView, maybe using filters

Comment: I think what you are looking for is "pagination".

Comment: @HighCore Would a CollectionView be too slow though, for doesn't it load the view then sort it after?

Comment: An example on how to do it with a CollectionView can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784726/how-can-i-paginate-a-wpf-datagrid

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  Why do you need to limit?  With virtualization you can get great performance on very large list.  Why do you assume a CollectionView is too slow?

Comment: @Blam I want to create a paging control that limits the number of page numbers in the view then have a button that says go tot the next ten and the next ten will appear. And I assume CollectionView will be too slow because I have used it to sort before and it was slow.

Comment: Then look at how you are using CollectionView as I sort and filter millions of rows in a fraction of a second.  The collection is in memory.